# What's a liquid antonym of vitriol (used figuratively)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there any liquids (like vitriol is actually sulfuric acid) that we appropriate figuratively to mean high praise (i.e., the antonym of vitriol)?

Comment: I think 'vitriolic' is not an antonym to 'high praise', but a description. There is critique, and there is vitriolic critique. There is praise, and there is high praise.

Comment: I said `vitriol`, not its adjective form; and it does mean particularly bitter criticism.

Comment: I was thinking of the milk of human kindness, but since you are looking for a single word, it's too long...

Comment: @ash None of my dictionaries describe vitriol as meaning criticism. Most describe it as 'particularly bitter' or 'caustic', for instance online Miriam Webster. Let me buffer this rather acid exchange with the balm of praise, and say it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'***Honey***' might be close.  It could be used to describe praise, but certainly doesn't mean praise. But '*words sweet as honey*' could be the opposite of '*words full of vitriol*'

Answer (score 7):

[balsamic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/balsamic) *(3) Restorative; curative.*

[This hymn](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rT-AGw-ZMpEC&pg=PA165&dq=%22balsamic%20words%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=obhzT6u8OMSZ0QXu7YnwDw&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22balsamic%20words%22&f=false) written mid C18 by clergyman / poet brothers [John and Charles Wesley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wesley)...

> With humble fear I now draw near,
>     In my forlorn condition,
>     Thy **balsamic words** to hear,
>     And prove thee my Physician.

...but possibly today people might think more readily of [balsamic vinegar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balsamic_vinegar) - which although relatively sweet, is still basically an acid.

Comment: *[Balsam](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balsam)* itself (in its sense "A sweet-smelling oil or resin derived from various plants") may serve better than *balsamic*.

Comment: @jwpat7: Surely. But if anyone thinks *balsamic* is useful, it's trivial to accept the implied *balsam* too. I concentrated on the adjectival form because [*vitriolic* is more common than *vitriol*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vitriol%2Cvitriolic&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) - particularly, I'm sure, in the metaphoric sense as it relates to use of language.

Comment: ...also note that *balsam* and [balm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=balsam) are etymologically speaking the same word. They're both synonymous with *salve*, healing /aromatic ointment, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Salve/Salving is a perfect antonym and is in reasonably common use. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Ben: I know the differences are vague, but to me, *salve* and *balm* are more like "soft cream" for rubbing into affected areas. *Balsam*, on the other hand, I see more as a liquid (in the UK we have [Friars Balsam](http://www.expresschemist.co.uk/Friars-Balsam-25ml.html))

Answer (score 5):

The most specific word I know of is *[libation](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/libation)* in its classical sense "A serving (of wine) poured out in honor of a deity".  However, its facetious sense, "a serving of an alcoholic beverage" probably is  used more often.

Terms *[ambrosia](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/Ambrosia)* ("the food and drink of the gods") and *[nectar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nectar)* ("The sweet drink of the Ancient gods") might be used figuratively; *eg* "Ann's ambrosial words soon slaked Tom's thirst for praise".  If you are writing humor you also can work in *[philtre](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/philtre)* ("A drink credited with magical power"), *[ardent spirits](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/ardent%20spirits)* ("strong distilled liquor"), and *[hair of the dog](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/hair%20of%20the%20dog)* ("An alcoholic drink supposed to cure a hangover").

Answer (score 1):

I would just go with ***laudanum***. About as far from vitriol as I can imagine, assuming you're just seeking a liquid noun.

Also, for your "liquid ... figuratively to mean high praise" notion, note that from etymonline, *[laudanum](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=laudanum)* is

> perhaps from L. *laudere* "to praise," or from L. *ladanum* "a gum resin"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [unction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unction?s=t).

Although the most prominent definitions refer specifically to the oil used in anointing, in my experience it tends to be used in general in the more metaphorical sense of something comforting or soothing.

Comment: No way! *Unctuous praise* is universally recognised as [the kind of praise](http://www.wordswarm.net/dictionary/unctuous.html) you *wouldn't* want to receive!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Vitriol is corrosive (and presumably honest); unction is soothing (and frequently dishonest). I still think they're pretty good antonyms.

Comment: Well I can't deny that, but as I noted in a comment to my own answer, the word *vitriolic* is in fact more common than *vitriol*. So if you're providing an antonym, particularly given that OP has mentioned *praise* as his primary context, it really needs to work as an adjective that you can apply to *praise*.

Comment: It may be true that *vitriolic* is more common than *vitriol*, but the question asked for an antonym for the latter. I think "balm", which you mentioned in your comment to your own answer, is also a pretty good antonym to "vitriol", though I'm not sure I'd want to supply a "balmy" answer. ;)

Comment: Yeah - so far, only *honeyed* and *ambrosial* really seem to work there. I admit I had to dig a bit to find my quoted *balsamic words*.

Answer (score 1):

***Vitriol*** literally means extremely strong acid, usually sulphuric acid.

In terms of its effect on a person, the antonym would be ***balm***, ***balsam*** or ***unction*** or some like thing, as others have already posted. One **burns**, the other **soothes**.

So the antonym of ***Vitriolic*** would literally be ***Balmy***, ***Balsamic*** or ***Unctious***. Unfortunately they all have negative associations, with insanity, vinegar, and false ingratiation, respectively.

So a better antonym for ***Vitriolic*** is probably ***Soothing***.

**Edit:** I just noticed FumbleFingers' suggestion of ***Salve***, which together with ***Salving*** are a good pair for this purpose if you need a pair, and are in common use. (Etymologically, ***Salve***/***Salving*** are the same as ***Save***/***Saving***, but *Salve* commonly means *Ointment*, and *Salving* is used for *Soothing*)

Comment: I just noticed @fumbleFingers suggestion of ***Salve*** and ***Salving*** which is even better.

Answer (score 1):

I second the nomination for ***balm***.  From Wordnik:

> **Balm** - n. An aromatic or soothing salve or oil; a soothing, healing, or comforting agent or quality; anything which heals,
>   soothes, or mitigates pain.
>
> v. To anoint with balm, or with anything medicinal. To soothe; to
>   mitigate.
>
> **Example**: “*But there was no indication that the move would be more than a short-term **balm** for the crisis engulfing the Eurozone*.”

Answer (score 0):

Right now I can't think of a liquid that by itself is a solid antonym. But given you're using the noun form of *vitriol*, and it often comes with a verb that can also work with a liquid, it seems to me that using a liquid-connoting verb could help make some nouns function as a liquid that normally don't.

- Spew vitriol
- Shower blessings/compliments/kindness
- Pour praise/accolades/encouragement

However, it's not always used with such a verb, as in "I've had enough of your vitriol." I still can't think of a liquid that would fit this construction, and be understood as an antonym or anything close.

The best I can do so far is: "I've had enough of your honeyed talk."